# How to calculate ISBN using C?

Tags: c, cs50

Below is my code that should calculate the ISBN number of a book:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int isbn[] = 0;
    printf("Please enter ISBN number: \n");

    scanf("%d", &isbn);
    int num = 0;
    int times_by = 1;
    long long sum;
    long long sum1;
    long long result = 0;
    for (num = 0; num <= 9; num++){
        sum = isbn[num] * times_by;
        sum1 = sum + sum;
        times_by++;
    }
    result = sum / 11;
    if (result == 0){
        printf("Yes\n");
    } 
    else {
        printf("No\n");
    }
}
```

It is telling me that there is a problem with the initiator of isbn. I tried to create an array, which the inputted ISBN number would be saved to after, though Im not sure if this is possible..

Comment: see (this answer)[https://stackoverflow.com/a/201116/3512524] about array initialization. It's a bit different that in python and JavaScript . First of all you need to put number of elements inside [ ]

Comment: Read the documentation for `scanf`. Are you using it correctly?

Comment: What compiler are you using? You need to **pay attention to the warnings**. If you're using GCC, always compile with `gcc -Wall -Werror`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem starts with `int isbn[]=0;` This declares an arry of no size, which can't be.

Then you read `isbn` as a single `int` and then you seem to want to calculate using each digit of the ISBN.

To do that, I suggest to declare `char isbn[14]={0};` (ISBN can be 13 characters, see [isbn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number)).

Then read it as `scanf("%13s", isbn);`

and process it like:

```
    sum = (isbn[num]-'0') * times_by; // convert digit to number
```

Note: `sum1 = sum + sum;` should be `sum1 = sum1 + sum;`

Note: `result = sum / 11;` should be `result = sum1 / 11;`

Note: you must initialize `sum1`: `long long sum1=0;`

Note: `result = sum1 / 11;` won't give you the remainder. Use `result = sum1 % 11;`

Comment: Agreed. If you're not going to use something for math, it should be an array of chars/ints, not a (single) integer. Thus, storing the ISBN as an array makes sense.

Comment: So I had tried that originally. It shows me this error " isbn.c:7:10: error: array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal
    char isbn[10] = 0;"

Comment: There are a few liitle bugs in your program, though I think I spotted most of them. But you should learn to use a debugger so you can step through your program and see in detail what it does and where you made the small (or sometimes large) mistakes.

Comment: OK: "error: array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal char isbn[10] = 0;" Then use curly braces, `isbn[10]={0};`

Comment: @chux, updated. Better to be correct than sloppy (which I already was...)

Answer (score 1):

The line `int isbn[] = 0;` is your problem you are pointing the array's address to 0x0 which is not a valid address space for your application.

You should initialize your isbn array in another way. For example `int isbn[20]`. You should give a length which is sufficient for ISBN numbers. I just used 20 as an example.